# Finding the specific entry of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a $5\times 5$ matrix $A$ and its' determinant $\Delta$, how can we find the specific entry $A^{-1}(2,4)$, where $A^{-1}$ is the  inverse of $A$, without using heavy computations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $A^{-1} (2,4)$ I assume you mean $a^{-1}_{24}$. The second row, 4th column element of the inverse.

Recall that $A^{-1}A = AA^{-1}= E$, the unit matrix of corresponding order.
Actually this not much helpful, if anything it is inferior to the alternative:

Determine the algebraic complement of $a_{42}$, that is the 4th row, 2nd column element's algebraic complement in matrix $A$ then divide it by $\det(A)$. We will have to calculate one $4\times 4$ determinant instead of calculating 25 $4\times 4$ determinants when we would want to find the entire inverse.

Fun facts:
By the mentioned method, total number of operations is 25 where as if we calculated the entire inverse, we would have done 601 (six hundred and one) operations. I think we have avoided heavy computation. $25 < 601$

Comment: But how can you use determinant in this case? Because i was given a determinant of a 5x5 matrix, so i guess i need to use it somehow.

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what qualifies as heavy computation. I think we can agree then, that, calculating the entire inverse out through conventional methods, is what we might call heavy computation.

We can use bits of it, though. $$A^{-1} =\frac{1}{\det(A)}adj A$$, which is fine since $A$ is invertible, meaning $\det(A)\neq 0$

So all we really need is the algebraic complement of $a_{42}$.

Comment: Yes, but then calculating adj of A will be certainly much more work than calculating the entire inverse out through conventional methods.

Comment: oh, i think i got it ! So we don't need to find the entire ajd of A, we just need to find the specific entry (2,4) and then divide it by determinant, right?

Comment: Yes, correct

Right now I would say, merely having $\det(A)$ and the invertibility of $A$, is not sufficient information to quickly calculate $a^{-1}_{ij}$.
We don't have to calculate the entire $adj A$, we only need its $4x4$ determinant of row 2, column 4. In other words, the algebraic complement of $a_{42}$ since it will be transposed.

Calculating out one $4\times 4$ determinant instead of 25 satsifies the criterion of avoiding heavy computation, I believe.

Comment: Oh, but then do i need to find the transpose of A first, and then find the cofactor of specific entry (2,4) since in order to find adjA i need to find the cofactors of each element and then take a transpose ?

Comment: Recall that when you find adj of A you form a $5\times 5$ matrix of algebraic complements corresponding to $a_{ij}$ and then you transpose that matrix. If you backtrack your steps, then you would have to determine the algebraic complement of $a_{42}$ of the original matrix $A$. Calculate its value, divide it by $\det (A)$ and _voila_ , that is the $a^{-1}_{24}$