# Derivative of a minor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

From matrix $Y_{T \times I}$ I can can calculate the covariance as follows: 
$$
S=\frac{1}{I}{Y^tY}
$$
and a singular entry of the inverse like so (as explained in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517510/finding-the-specific-entry-of-inverse-matrix)):
$$
s_{i,j}^{-1} = \frac{(-1)^{i+j}M_{j,i}}{\det(S)}
$$
where $M_{j,i}$ is a minor taken from  $S^T$. What would $\frac{\delta(s_{i,j}^{-1})}{\delta{y_{t,i}}}$ be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \alpha Y^TY$

Then
$$\eqalign{
 \alpha S^{-1}Y^T &= (Y^TY)^{-1}Y^T = Y^+ \cr
 \alpha YS^{-1} &= Y(Y^TY)^{-1} = (Y^+)^T \cr
}$$ where $Y^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $Y$.

Taking the requested differential
$$\eqalign{
 dS^{-1}
  &= -S^{-1}\,dS\,S^{-1} \cr
  &= -S^{-1}\,\alpha(dY^T\,Y+Y^T\,dY)\,S^{-1} \cr
  &= -S^{-1}\,dY^T\,\alpha YS^{-1} - \alpha S^{-1}Y^T\,dY\,S^{-1} \cr
  &= -S^{-1}\,dY^T\,(Y^+)^T - Y^+\,dY\,S^{-1} \cr\cr
 dS^{-1}_{ij}
  &= -S^{-1}_{im}\,dY^T_{mn}\,(Y^+)^T_{nj} - Y^+_{im}\,dY_{mn}\,S^{-1}_{nj} \cr
  &= -S^{-1}_{im}\,dY_{nm}\,Y^+_{jn} - Y^+_{im}\,dY_{mn}\,S^{-1}_{nj} \cr
}$$
And applying the basic gradient for these situations:
$$\frac{\partial Y_{ij}}{\partial Y_{kl}} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$$
Yields
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial S^{-1}_{ij}}{\partial Y_{kl}}
  &= -S^{-1}_{im}\,\delta_{nk}\delta_{ml}\,Y^+_{jn} - Y^+_{im}\,\delta_{mk}\delta_{nl}\,S^{-1}_{nj} \cr
  &= -S^{-1}_{il}Y^+_{jk} - Y^+_{ik}S^{-1}_{lj} \cr
}$$
I know that you were hoping for something in terms of the minors, but nothing like that occurs to me.

Comment: Nice, how did you set the indexes in $dS^{-1}_{ij}$ before applying the gradient? Also, $\frac{\partial Y_{ij}}{\partial Y_{kl}} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$ only works when all elements of Y are independent right?

Comment: The leftmost index on each term is $i$, the rightmost is $j$, and all the ones in-between are dummies. If there is some constraint, that makes the elements of $Y$ interdependent, then by all means apply it.